# Probability of opening the locks

Tags: probability

There are two identical locks with two identical keys and the key are among six different ones which a person carries in his pocket. In a hurry, he drops one key somewhere. Then the probability that the locks can still be opened by drawing one key at random is?

I am a newbie to probability and I am learning it for my competitive exam, so please forgive me if I ask some really silly questions.

Here if I understand the problem, then there are 2 similar locks and they have the same key,(Means we have 2 keys and either of them is capable of opening the lock). Now, these two keys are in a set of 6 keys. One key is dropped by the person.

The probability that locks can still be opened by drawing one key at random should be like:

The favourable case will be when the keys of locks are still available=2.

Total cases=5(One key is lost)

So, probability=$\frac{2}{5}$

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not correct.

Given that there are $6$ keys in which $2$ are identical and with $2$ keys we can open the lock.

Given that he dropped $1$ key. So, $5$ are remaining.

So, the probability is $\dfrac56$

Now,  we need both keys which can open the lock.

So, the probability is $\dfrac25$

Now, the total probability is $\dfrac56\times\dfrac25=\dfrac13$

Comment: Have you made use of Conditional probability?
$P(A|B)$?

Comment: I didn't get why are you multiplying by $\frac{5}{6}$

Comment: @user3767495 $\dfrac56$ is the probability among $5$ keys and $\dfrac25$ is the probability that exactly $2$ keys open. So, in total we multiplied.

Comment: -No not this approach. But after thinking alot on this, I was able to develop a new approach to solve this :)

Comment: I thought the same approach as described by N.F. Taussig

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the question could be improved.  My understanding is that there are initially six keys in his pocket.  Of these, two are identical and will open the identical locks he wishes to open.

Since the person drops a key, there are two possibilities.  Either he drops one of the two keys that will open the lock or he drops one of the other four keys.  Let $A$ be the event that he drops one of the two keys that will open the lock.  Let $B$ be the event that he chooses a key that opens the lock.  If he drops one of the two keys that will open the lock, then one of the remaining five keys will open the lock.  If he drops one of the other four keys, then two of the remaining five keys will open the lock.  Then the probability he manages to open the lock is
$$\Pr(B) = \Pr(B \mid A)\Pr(A) + \Pr(B \mid A^C)\Pr(A^C) = \frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{6} + \frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{1}{15} + \frac{4}{15} = \frac{1}{3}$$